# OData4J consumer not mapping JPA Entity property values if the properties are camelcase

Tags: java, rest, jpa, odata, odata4j

I have published a OData4J service using JPA Producer and I am able to see the metadata and EntitySet/Entity values properly.

But when I try to obtain the data using `ODataConsumer.getEntities(User.class, "User").execute();` I am getting the beans but the properties values are not populated with data, they are all nulls.

On further investigation what I observed is if the properties are in **camel case** (empId, firstName etc) they are not being mapped properly. Instead if they are like EmpId, FirstName then they are being mapped correctly.

Is it how odata4j works? Is there any way we can tweak and make it work with camel case properties?